# PayPal integration in flutter

Tags: flutter, paypal, payment

I am using this package but  I am facing some problem when I click on pay pal it did not open anything. is there another way to implement pay Pal integration in flutter application? 
package name braintree_payment 
https://pub.dev/packages/braintree_payment

Comment: Which package ?

Comment: braintree_payment
https://pub.dev/packages/braintree_payment

Comment: pay pal is as payment processor. I am looking for this integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of paypal I worked on stripe payment through cloud function I would recommend you to write a cloud function which uses paypal integration. I am sure cloud function have support to paypal.

[How to write cloud function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/)

[Paypal with nodejs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/express-checkout/ec-braintree-sdk/server-side/node/)

Comment: Can you tell me the flow ?

Comment: I would recommend you to follow these links once just get an overview

Comment: it simply you need to write cloud function which will read the data and trigger the cloud function . from you application you send some data to fire base database , cloud function will scene the data and run your function. you can get back a response after payment successfully done.

Comment: Hi, can you provide some more info on how you have integrated Stripe payment with Cloud Functions and Flutter? I'm assuming this method will also work for Flutter web? I need help with this...